# Get the fields of Foreign key values in Django

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, django, ajax

I'm confused why the values I fetch in foreign key is missing or not pops in Ajax result , all I want is to get the value name through the foreign key id using **ajax**, I tried many ways like `select_related()` but it doesn't work.

The image below shows the result of the ajax through `consolelog` which contains data from `supplier table` and `supplier_type table` but only the supplier table fetch the data and missing supplier name data which foreign key name? I just tried `supplier_type__name` but it seems doesn't work. Is there any problem with the implementation?

[image]

**ajax**

```
$('.get_supplier_details').click(function (event) {

  var patient_id = $('#selected-patient').find(":selected").val();

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "{% url 'supplier-details' %}",
    data:{
        supplier: supplier_id
    }
    }).done(function(data){
      console.log(data);  //

    });

});
```

**vies.py**

```
from main.models import (Supplier, SupplierType)

def patientdetails(request):
   supplier_id = request.POST.get('supplier')
   clients = Supplier.objects.filter(id=supplier_id ).select_related()
   qs_json = serializers.serialize('json', clients, fields=['first_name', 'middle_name', 'supplier_type__name'])

   return JsonResponse({'data': qs_json})
```

**models,py**

```
class SupplierType(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True, null=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True, auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True, auto_now=True)
    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'supplier_type'

class Supplier(models.Model):
    supplier_type = models.ForeignKey(SupplierType, models.DO_NOTHING)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True, null=True)
    middle_name = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True, null=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True, null=True)
    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'supplier'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, serialization of foreign key fields isn't that simple.  You'll either need to plug in the [django rest framework](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#primarykeyrelatedfield) (well worth getting your head around), or, if that's overkill for this situation, you could can just convert to a list and use the JsonResponse method you have already. JsonResponse can actually encode by istelf so you don't need a serializer.

```
#JsonResponse wants a list rather than a queryset, so convert via list()
qs_list = list(
         (Supplier.objects
             .filter(id=supplier_id)
             .select_related('supplier_type')
             #we only want to return specific fields
             .values('first_name','middle_name', 'supplier_type__name')
         )
)

return JsonResponse({'data': qs_list})
```

Comment: I tried this but only the` firstname` and `middlename` reflects in `json` the `name` of foreign key didn't reflect

Comment: Thought of a better way to handle this and updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks it works and you're right, it helps me a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Get the SupplierType ID and store it in variable in your func.

Then Supplier.objects.filter(supplier_type_contains=supplier_id).

This is dynamic way to store it on the go from value you may get from Ajax posted for django.

You don't need to use prefetch_related or select_related serialization.

Comment: It helped me solve my problem. Thanks @Mudassar. :-)

Comment: @Shazia Nusrat how did you do it? I tried this but it didn't reflect the name of my foreign key did you use `ajax response`?

Comment: @Mudassar Hashmi it says `Related Field got invalid lookup: contains`

Comment: Okay I tried it on my side. We use to get current user from the "request context" in django. when in a function you pass request, and ID as argument. Then you use "supplier_id = request.id". Now you do have ID from the UI and need to filter that ID from any model generally. That is where you can run the query. Try passing "id" variable in your function where you say "def patentdetails(request, id):. Hope it helps.

Comment: We need to divide problem in two pieces. 1. Just focus on the queryset as I suggested. After you are done with the query. You already are doing it right way for serialization. Please use django shell with "python manage.py shell" import your models and try queryset as humbly suggested. Good Lukc